# Handling cached entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

My application uses Code First Entity Framework to manage "Scripts".  Scripts can have multiple "Tags" associated to them.

```
public class Tag
{
    public Guid TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Script> Scripts { get; set; }
}

public class Script
{
    public Guid ScriptId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    ...

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; } = new List<Tag>();
}
```

When the application starts up it loads a list of all the tags and keeps references to them.  When the user edits a script they can add and remove tags on the script.  As the user adds tags I simply use `script.Tags.Add(tag)` to add the reference.  When I save the Script everything works fine the first time, but on subsequent scripts it ends up saving multiple copies of the older scripts and creates duplicate Tags.

I know exactly why it happens.  When I call `Context.SaveChanges` it fixes up the references and adds the script to the tag's Script collection, which then persist for the next save.  What I don't know is, what is the proper way to prevent this from happening?

I've come up with a few solutions that work, but none of them seem ideal, and some of them have serious down-sides.  They will also start becoming increasingly complex and error-prone as the application grows and I start having more associations like this.  I feel I must be missing something obvious.

- Clear the `.Scripts` property of each `Tag` after saving.
- Before saving, mark the tags as "unchanged" in the context so it doesn't try to save them.
- Reload a new copy of each `Tag` in to the context that is used to save the `Script`.
- Use a single `Context` for the entire life of the application.

What is the proper "Entity Framework Way" of handling this pattern?

Comment: Who creates the tag key - you or the database? Are you creating a new Tag (instance) each time a user add tags? If so, this is the issue. If a tag already was created you should use that instance to add to the collection and not a new instance each time.

Comment: All keys are generated by the database.  A list of all the tags are loaded from the database at application start, although additional tags can be created.  I 'm adding existing the Tag instances to the Script objects (not creating new ones).

Comment: Is this a web or desktop application? A "single `Context` for the entire life of the application" is not feasible in a web app.

Comment: It is a WPF application for the desktop.  As I said, all the solutions I listed, including a single context, have serious issues. I don't intend to use any of them unless there is no other choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to draw the junction class into the class model:

```
public class Tag
{
    public Guid TagId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ScriptTag
{
    public Guid ScriptId { get; set; }
    public Guid TagId { get; set; }
    public virtual Script Script { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

public class Script
{
    public Guid ScriptId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<ScriptTag> ScriptTags { get; set; }
        = new List<ScriptTag>();
}
```

Now you can manipulate the script-tag associations directly without having to load a single `Tag` object into the context that does the job. The user can make a selection from the preloaded tags and you only have to create/delete these lightweight `ScriptTag` entities accordingly.

Suppose you have a `viewModel` object containing selected tags, this is a way to do it:

```
var script = db.Scripts.Include(s => s.ScriptTags)
               .Single(s => s.ScriptId == scriptId);

// Simply replace the `ScriptTags` collection.
script.ScriptTags.Clear();
script.ScriptTags.AddRange(viewModel.Tags.Select(t => new ScriptTag
    {
        ScriptId = scriptId,
        TagId = t.TagId
    });

db.SaveChanges();
```

And this is how to get all tags of a script:

```
from script in db.Scripts
where script.ScriptId == scriptId
from scriptTag in script.ScripTags
select scriptTag.Tag.Name
```

Comment: Ahh, exactly the type of answer I was looking for. I hadn't even thought of trying to manage the junction table directly.